# One Angular Reactive forms at two places with different functionality

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an angular 2 reactive form component. I want use this component at two places. At one place the form is read-only and at other place it should be editable. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When initialising each field on the form, you can pass in the value to say if it is disabled or not:

Input for the comonent:

```
@Input() isDisabled;
```

Initialise form fields:

```
myInput: [{ value: "some value", disabled: isDisabled }, Validators.required],
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a component parameter, like a boolean "readOnly", and pass that parameter to your input's "readonly" attributes.

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/components/app_structure/passing_data_into_components.html